# play audio in sequence Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game in Unity.

I have a list of sounds.

When the player collides with an object, I want to play the 1st sound in the sound array. The second time player collides with that same object, I want to play the 2nd sound and so on.

When it reaches the end of the array, it will loop through the list again.

So I try to make a loop for that, and I called the function inside `onTrigger2d`. in player class.

However, it always plays the 1st sound in the list with every collision.

This is the code:

```
public class PlayNotes : MonoBehaviour
{


    public AudioSource adSource;
    public AudioClip[] adClips;

    public void PlayNote()
    {
        //--1.Loop through each audio clip--
        for ( int i = 0; i < adClips.Length; i++)
        {
            //--2.Assign current audio clip to audiosource--
            adSource.clip = adClips[i];

            //--3.play audio--
            adSource.Play();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do not share your code in image file

Comment: sorry I'm new to this, Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are starting all sounds at once! Remember that your entire loop is executed in one single go. Actually I would rather expect only the last sound in your array to be played.

---

In general I would rather use [`AudioSource.PlayOneShot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html) in your use case in order to not interrupt currently playing sounds but allow multiple concurrent sounds. E.g. for letting a sound finish playing with reverb etc while the next hit already triggers the next sound so they blend together. If you use [`AudioSource.Play`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html) it will stop playing the current clip and only play the new one.

And then simply add a counter for the currently played clip index with wrap around like e.g.

```
public class PlayNotes : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource adSource;
    public AudioClip[] adClips;

    // Index of the currently played sound
    private int index;

    public void PlayNote()
    {  
        // Play current sound
        // I would rather use PlayOneShot in order to allow multiple concurrent sounds
        adSource.PlayOneShot(adClips[index]);

        // Increase the index, wrap around if reached end of array
        index = (index + 1) % adClips.Length;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your time! It helped me a lot